# Attach to debugger events from code being debugged?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, events, debugging

Are there any events that Visual Studio raises while debugging that I could subscribe to in the code? Specifically, I'd like to know when a debugger is detached or stops. Thanks

Comment: No, the debugger must always run in another process.  You can only poll.  Setting a breakpoint and editing a variable value is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a separate thread you could check the `Debugger.IsAttached` method and generate events accordingly.

EDIT: I just whipped this up, see if it works.

```
 public class DebuggerEvents {

     public delegate void DebuggingStatusChanged(EventArgs e);
     public event DebuggingStatusChanged DebuggerAttached;
     public event DebuggingStatusChanged DebuggerUnattached;

     private readonly Thread workerThread;
     public DebuggerEvents() {
         var threadStart = new ThreadStart(BackgoundWorker);
         workerThread = new Thread(threadStart);
         workerThread.Start();
     }


     private void BackgoundWorker() {
      bool currentStateflag = Debugger.IsAttached;
         while (true) {

             if (Debugger.IsAttached && !currentStateflag){
                 DebuggerAttached(new EventArgs());
                 currentStateflag = true;
             }

             if (!Debugger.IsAttached && currentStateflag){
                 DebuggerUnattached(new EventArgs());
                 currentStateflag = false;
             }

             Thread.Sleep(100);
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Using this technique, if I hit the stop button, is my event handler guaranteed to finish executing before the process ends?

Comment: Probably not. You'll need to test tho

Comment: Probably won't work for me then. I wanted to roll back a transaction and it might take a few seconds.

Comment: Tried to get it to write to a file after I hit the stop button, no luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Still, this may work for people attaching and detaching from a running process that doesn't end. I'll keep this in mind if I run into that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

Also look up conditional compilation symbols and pay attention to the DEBUG symbol.